# Solution to wirelessly project tablet desktop?

Tags: windows-7, wifi, display

I’m trying to find a device that would allow a windows 7 client to wirelessly connect and display their screen to a projector while still connected to the wireless network.  The idea is to allow a professor to still project and display content while walking around the room with their tablet.  To date, haven’t been able to find a solution that meets the requirements, has anyone stumbled across one yet?

Requirements

- Must support Windows 7
- Must be able to connect to WPA2 Personal(and hopefully enterprise)
- Must not use any usb dongles – those get lost/damaged given a chance.

Goal

- Wirelessly display screen to projector without cables from tablet/laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We opted to go with: http://www.teqavit.com/WiD410.html to solve our needs.  It actually does full motion video good enough!

Answer (score 2):

Would something like the [LiteShow product from inFocus](http://www.infocus.com/Accessories/Wireless/LiteShowII.aspx) do the trick?

Comment: I thought so too - but when I called and talked to them it doesn't support windows 7 and they said they are reviewing if they even want to support windows 7 or just shelf the product line.  o.O

Answer (score 1):

If your projector handles the protocol Windows seven has a built in [Connect to Network Projector](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Network-projectors-frequently-asked-questions) feature built in to its core system.

Comment: +1 Use a networked projector ^^

Answer (score 0):

Attach a computer to the projector. Set up vnc on the computer and the laptop.

Set up a VNC connection from the computer to the laptop. This should allow what's happening on the laptop to be displayed on the projector.

Comment: That might work out but it's cludgey at best.  I'll start working on testing it out, I'm out for a week starting tommorow though so it'll be a few days before I can test it out.

Comment: it's free though (apart from the computer obviously!)

Answer (score 0):

Any Windows PC running Remote Desktop could handle this. Hook that PC directly up to the projector, and then have the professor open an RDP session to it, from his/her tablet PC. A wireless connection has enough bandwidth and low enough latency to make RDP seem as responsive as a local session.

Comment: Isn't remote desktop not running at the console, so it wouldn't show up at that projector since the session would be virtual? I'm thinking you'd want something more akin to VNC to control the console session.

Comment: That might work out but it's cludgey at best.  I'll start working on testing it out, I'm out for a week starting tommorow though so it'll be a few days before I can test it out.